# Make control for create user

Tags: apex

I want to do a control on the accounts.
I want to get a list of accounts, then a list of Siret fields on the account, then make a SOQL query, and then I don't know how to proceed.
I want to make a control that checks if the Siret of an account already exists, we check in which Record type it is and if the Siret already exists in the record type we block the possibility to create a new account, otherwise we leave the possibility to create a new account.

this is what I have already done

```
public static void reglesDoublonsComptes (List<Account> accounts){
     List<Account> acclst = new List<Account>();
     List<Account> siretlst = new List<Account>([SELECT Siret__c FROM Account]);
     List<Account> acc = [SELECT Id, Siret__c, RecordTypeID FROM Account];
     Map<String, Account> accMap = new Map<String, Account>();
        
        for (Account a : accounts) {
            if(a.Siret__c == acc.Siret__c){
                if (a.RecordTypeID == acc.RecordTypeID){
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have try to make this with Matching Rules and Duplicates Rules but RecordTypeID is not available in field.

Comment: Take a look at Matching and Duplicate Rules: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/sales_admin_duplicate_management . Create a matching rule that compares two Accounts and declares them duplicate if `Siret__c` and `RecordTypeID` are the same, et voila.

Comment: I have try with Matching Rules, but we can't use the field RecordTypeID in Matching or duplicate Rules

Comment: That's correct, apologies. Please vote for [this idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdfX1UAJ/include-record-type-as-a-field-option-for-matching-rules). Your options: 1) Create a duplicate rule _per_ record type. Duplicate rules can filter on the record type. Many dupe rules, 1 matching rule. 2)  Create a Text field and use your favorite automation approach (Apex triggers, Flows, ...) to set this field to the value of `RecordTypeId`, it'll then be available to Dup/Matching rules.